# Get value of key from object using variable and object

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I'm trying to get a value from my object using variable and another object.
The first variable worked very well, but is get stuck at the second one and tried a lot of things without success.

```
console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i]);
console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i[sessionStorage.language]]);
console.log(sessionStorage.language);
```

The first line returns;

```
Object {nl: "April", en: "April", de: ""}
```

Second line returns;

```
undefined
```

Third line returns

```
nl
```

I need to get 'April'

**Added later**

In the example below `data` is retrieved with ajax call, from original it's json but ajax transfer it inside a object.

Only in this example i placed 'var data' manually with the full ajax response, in my example it's not transferred into object.

My goal is to loop trough each image and take the image and the label in the right language what is part of the image.

```
var data = {
  "code": "0",
  "success": [],
  "error": [],
  "data": {
    "0": "1",
    "mengsels_id": "1",
    "1": "Data Removed",
    "mengsels_name": "Data Removed",
    "2": "-",
    "mengsels_description": "-",
    "3": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg",
    "mengsels_cover": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg",
    "4": "",
    "mengsels_folder": "",
    "5": "",
    "mengsels_video": "",
    "6": "1",
    "mengsels_visible": "1",
    "7": "{\"mengsels_name\":\"Data Removed\",\"mengsels_description\":\"-\",\"mengsels_cover\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-1.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_1\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-1.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_2\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-2.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_3\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-3.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_4\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-4.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_5\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-5.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_6\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-6.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_7\":\"\",\"mengsels_img_8\":\"\",\"mengsels_img_9\":\"\",\"mengsels_img_10\":\"\",\"mengsels_label_1\":{\"nl\":\"Januari\",\"en\":\"Januari\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_2\":{\"nl\":\"Februari\",\"en\":\"Februari\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_3\":{\"nl\":\"Maart\",\"en\":\"March\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_4\":{\"nl\":\"April\",\"en\":\"April\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_5\":{\"nl\":\"Mei\",\"en\":\"May\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_6\":{\"nl\":\"Juni\",\"en\":\"June\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_7\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_8\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_9\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_10\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"}}",
    "mengsels_data": {
      "mengsels_name": "Data Removed",
      "mengsels_description": "-",
      "mengsels_cover": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg",
      "mengsels_img_1": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg",
      "mengsels_img_2": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-2.jpg",
      "mengsels_img_3": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-3.jpg",
      "mengsels_img_4": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-4.jpg",
      "mengsels_img_5": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-5.jpg",
      "mengsels_img_6": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-6.jpg",
      "mengsels_img_7": "",
      "mengsels_img_8": "",
      "mengsels_img_9": "",
      "mengsels_img_10": "",
      "mengsels_label_1": {
        "nl": "Januari",
        "en": "Januari",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_2": {
        "nl": "Februari",
        "en": "Februari",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_3": {
        "nl": "Maart",
        "en": "March",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_4": {
        "nl": "April",
        "en": "April",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_5": {
        "nl": "Mei",
        "en": "May",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_6": {
        "nl": "Juni",
        "en": "June",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_7": {
        "nl": "",
        "en": "",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_8": {
        "nl": "",
        "en": "",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_9": {
        "nl": "",
        "en": "",
        "de": ""
      },
      "mengsels_label_10": {
        "nl": "",
        "en": "",
        "de": ""
      }
    }
  }
};
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://xxx.xxx.xx/xxx/x.x/mengsels/?action=view",
  data: {
    mengsels_id: mengsels_id
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#stage').html("");
    var counter_i = 0;
    for (var match in data.data.mengsels_data) {
      var reg = /(mengsels_img_[0-9]{1,})/g;
      if (reg.exec(match)) {
        if (data.data.mengsels_data[match]) {
          $('#stage').append('<div class="slideshow-div slideshow-2" data-counter="' + counter_i + '"> \
                                  <div class="slideshow-image" style="background-image: url(\'https://xxx.xxx.xx' + data.data.mengsels_data[match] + '\');" class="slideshow-image"> \
                                  </div><span></span> \
                                </div>');
          console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_' + counter_i]);
          console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_' + counter_i][sessionStorage.language]);
          console.log(counter_i);
          console.log(sessionStorage.language);
          console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_' + counter_i]['nl']);
          console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_' + counter_i].nl);
          counter_i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you mistyped something. Can you try 

`console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i][sessionStorage.language]); ?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nl` is a property of `data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i]`
and `sessionStorage.language` === `nl`. So you should be able to use:

`data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i][sessionStorage.language]`

Edit based on new code:

The code you have is starting the counter at `0` but the data starts at `mengsels_label_1`, which means on the first iteration you are looking for `mengsels_label_0`, which doesn't exist. Try starting at `1`:

```js
var data = {"code": "0","success": [],"error": [],"data": {"0": "1","mengsels_id": "1","1": "Data Removed","mengsels_name": "Data Removed","2": "-","mengsels_description": "-","3": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg","mengsels_cover": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg","4": "","mengsels_folder": "","5": "","mengsels_video": "","6": "1","mengsels_visible": "1","7": "{\"mengsels_name\":\"Data Removed\",\"mengsels_description\":\"-\",\"mengsels_cover\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-1.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_1\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-1.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_2\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-2.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_3\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-3.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_4\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-4.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_5\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-5.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_6\":\"\\\/media\\\/mengsels\\\/data-removed\\\/data-removed-6.jpg\",\"mengsels_img_7\":\"\",\"mengsels_img_8\":\"\",\"mengsels_img_9\":\"\",\"mengsels_img_10\":\"\",\"mengsels_label_1\":{\"nl\":\"Januari\",\"en\":\"Januari\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_2\":{\"nl\":\"Februari\",\"en\":\"Februari\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_3\":{\"nl\":\"Maart\",\"en\":\"March\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_4\":{\"nl\":\"April\",\"en\":\"April\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_5\":{\"nl\":\"Mei\",\"en\":\"May\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_6\":{\"nl\":\"Juni\",\"en\":\"June\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_7\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_8\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_9\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"},\"mengsels_label_10\":{\"nl\":\"\",\"en\":\"\",\"de\":\"\"}}","mengsels_data": {"mengsels_name": "Data Removed","mengsels_description": "-","mengsels_cover": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg","mengsels_img_1": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-1.jpg","mengsels_img_2": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-2.jpg","mengsels_img_3": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-3.jpg","mengsels_img_4": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-4.jpg","mengsels_img_5": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-5.jpg","mengsels_img_6": "\/media\/mengsels\/data-removed\/data-removed-6.jpg","mengsels_img_7": "","mengsels_img_8": "","mengsels_img_9": "","mengsels_img_10": "","mengsels_label_1": {"nl": "Januari","en": "Januari","de": ""},"mengsels_label_2": {"nl": "Februari","en": "Februari","de": ""},"mengsels_label_3": {"nl": "Maart","en": "March","de": ""},"mengsels_label_4": {"nl": "April","en": "April","de": ""},"mengsels_label_5": {"nl": "Mei","en": "May","de": ""},"mengsels_label_6": {"nl": "Juni","en": "June","de": ""},"mengsels_label_7": {"nl": "","en": "","de": ""},"mengsels_label_8": {"nl": "","en": "","de": ""},"mengsels_label_9": {"nl": "","en": "","de": ""},"mengsels_label_10": {"nl": "","en": "","de": ""}}}};

function test(data) {
    const sessionStorage = {language: "nl"}
    var counter_i = 1; // <-- start at 1
    for (var match in data.data.mengsels_data) {
        var reg = /(mengsels_img_[0-9]{1,})/g;
        if (reg.exec(match)) {
          if (data.data.mengsels_data[match]) {      
            console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_' + counter_i][sessionStorage.language]);
            counter_i++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
test(data)
```

Comment: I just tried your example but that gave me the error: `app.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nl' of undefined`

Comment: There are no differences between our answers. However, both are different from your code. Take a look and you'll notice that your code is accessing the wrong array position, because a misplaced `]`

Comment: Then you need to make a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) @JQuest . Because your error is saying `data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i]` is undefined, but you just told us it wasn't.

Comment: It isn't undefined, it makes it undefined when I place [sessionStorage.language] at the second, this even makes the first one undefined in my console.log. I will look if i can create a complete example.

Comment: A runnable example that shows the error will definitely help @JQuest.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm not able to make an runnable example, but i placed the full code in it with the full json ajax response.

Comment: @JQuest I think your problem is caused by starting the counter at 0 when the first thing you want is `mengsels_label_1` Maybe the edit above will help.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you saved my life!! that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misplaced a `]`. Can you try the following code:

```
console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i]);
console.log(data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i][sessionStorage.language]);
console.log(sessionStorage.language);
```

If `data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i]` is equal to `Object {nl: "April", en: "April", de: ""}`, then your second line should access the `nl` by using `data.data.mengsels_data['mengsels_label_'+counter_i][sessionStorage.language]`.

Comment: This also doesn't work, i tried that before. Problem is very strange, i updated my question with more code.